# JSON.parse error when adding jwt to header

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm running into an issue when sending a request from my react/redux front end to my API. The API endpoint expects a jwt token in the "api-key" header, however, I get a JSON.parse error `SON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` when trying to send the request.

I'm assuming this is because of how JWT is formatted which prevents JSON from being parsed, but I can't wrap my head around it. Thanks.

When creating my backend I didn't consider this issue and so thought using a JWT as an api key would be fine. Ideally I'd like to continue to use this implementation.

an example of the JWT: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVjMzMzNWJkZDY2NmM5MmYxMGQxMDU3MyIsInBlcm1pc3Npb25zIjowLCJ2IjowLCJpYXQiOjE1NDY4NTk5NjV9.WIL6vCO95BEV7DWbRMheAwIRRoYO3cQQbzPdIRVv4tI`

**Fetch request:**

```
export const getUserData = token => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {

        console.log(typeof token);


        const response = await fetch("/api/user/data", {
            method: "post",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "api-key": token
            })
        });

        const responseBody = await response.json();

        console.log("Response JSON Body:", responseBody);


        if (!response.ok) return dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: responseBody.message });

        if (response.ok) return dispatch({ type: GET_USER_DATA, payload: responseBody });
    };
};
```

Comment: What do you see in the Response when you look at the request in the Network tab of Developer Tools?

Comment: Simple, the token probably caused a server side error and a non JSON response was sent. Try `await response.text()` instead and also add a catch to your fetch:  `fetch(/* ... */).catch(e=>console.log(e))`

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked catching the error on the fetch request. the app hangs and I receive an error now of: `TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`. I think it has something to do with the JWT as the request works flawlessly when providing the token as "test" or any other dummy string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kemicofa stated in the comments, if your problem is from `JSON.parse` then what we have to focus in is the server response, not your server request.

The code should be ready to receive a bad response from the server and act accordingly:

**Fetch request:**

```
export const getUserData = token => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {

        console.log(typeof token);


        const response = await fetch("/api/user/data", {
            method: "post",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "api-key": token
            })
        });


        let responseBody;
        try {
            responseBody = await response.json();
        } catch (e) {
            responseBody = await response.text();
            console.error('Server error response %s. json parse failed with error %s', responseBody, e.message)
            return dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: responseBody });
        }
        console.log("Response JSON Body:", responseBody);


        if (!response.ok) return dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: responseBody.message });

        if (response.ok) return dispatch({ type: GET_USER_DATA, payload: responseBody });
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the catch statement and now log the error returned by the fetch request. the app hangs and I receive an error now of: `TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`. I think it has something to do with the JWT as the request gets to my API when providing the token as "test" or any other dummy string.

Comment: As with most errors, it turned out to be a simple thing I overlooked. Thanks so much for your time and pointing me in the right direction with checking for errors on the fetch request. Turns out that the route should have been a GET request.